# Setup of vue.config.js file to imitate production setup (connect two apps)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, shiny, webpack-dev-server

I run an R Shiny app on port 3000 which serves my vue.js App like this:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  histogramData <- reactive({
      mtcars
  })
  
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("histogramData", histogramData())
  })
}

ui <- function() {
  htmlTemplate("dist/index.html")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/js")) {
  addResourcePath("js", "dist/js")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/css")) {
  addResourcePath("css", "dist/css")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/img")) {
  addResourcePath("img", "dist/img")
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For development, I would change it like this:

```
ui <- function() {
  htmlTemplate("public/index.html")
}
```

However, I can not always run the build process just to connect the apps, I want to use the dev server to connect the apps and send data back and forth.

I have setup a `vue.config.js` with the following configuration to create a connection between the two apps.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  publicPath: ".",
  devServer: {
    port: 4000,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000'
      },
      '/websocket': {
        target: 'ws://localhost:3000',
        ws: true
      }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

This was taken from a github repository, I am acutally quite clueless how to archieve this connection. My idea was to connect go on `localhost:4000` and receive the data from `localhost:3000`, but nothing gets passed:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCustomMessageHandler' of undefined at VueComponent.mounted (HelloWorld.vue?140d:42)`

This is based on the following method in my vue component (which works perfectly after the build process):

```
mounted: function () {
  window.Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('histogramData', histogramData =>
  this.data.histogramData = histogramData
)
```

Can anyone tell me what´s wrong and help me to setup the connection correctly?

Comment: The current issue is that window doesn't have the "Shiny" property so the function call to addCustomMessageHandler is on an undefined reference. How does one usually define window.Shiny?

Comment: That has to be set inside the index.html. I guess I found a workaround without the dev server: I now just use the `--watch` flag after the build script it so far it works fast enough